# nginx complaining about port 80 being in use

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

Whenever I try to start nginx I get the following output.

```
/etc/init.d/nginx start
Starting nginx: [emerg]: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
[emerg]: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
[emerg]: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
[emerg]: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
[emerg]: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
[emerg]: still could not bind()
nginx.
```

However, nothing is listening on port 80.  I get nothing when I run lsof -i :80

I'm also running php-fpm which I thought might have something to do with it but as I said, lsof doesn't indicate that php-fpm is related.

Does anyone have any idea what to look for?

Comment: What does `netstat -tanp` show? What do you get if you telnet to port 80?

Comment: Nothing for port 80 in netstat or telnet.

Comment: Can you post your config?

Answer (score 0):

Try starting nginx manually at the command line and see if you have the same problem.  Try it with a clean config file and slowly add your changes.  Maybe it's as simple as a configuration issue.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty obvious, but you never know: are you starting this as root or via sudo? Only root can bind to ports < 1024.

Comment: Trying to bind to a privileged port as a non-root user gives `EACCES`, not `EADDRINUSE`.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a problem with the config file. Kind-of disturbed that a config file problem reports as an unrelated inability to bind to a port.

Comment: What kind of a problem? Can you please post what options in your config file were causing such behaviour?

Answer (score -2):

My guess is that Apache is taking it. I'm pretty sure that PHP cannot run without it. I'm not very confident with PHP config. Here's a link that I found that may help. http://www.howtoforge.com/nginx_php5_fast_cgi_xcache_ubuntu7.04

I hope that this helps a little.

Comment: -1 No, PHP does not require Apache and that link has nothing to do with PHP requiring Apache, or even using Apache...